# Hazelcast serializer uuid not workging

Tags: java, serialization, hazelcast

I get an error when caching with hazelcast after several searches and requests for results on github I still don't have a solution. Here is my problem I would like to store a booster in an IMAP which contains the uuid and the Booster object in the booster object so I have the uuid the type of booster and who it is activated by and at the time of saving it in the error map.

Here is the code and errors obtained

```
        ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();

        clientConfig.getSerializationConfig().setAllowOverrideDefaultSerializers(true);

        clientConfig.getSerializationConfig()
                .getCompactSerializationConfig()
                .addSerializer(new CustomUUIDSerializer());

        clientConfig.getNetworkConfig().addAddress("hazelcast-service:5701");

        this.hazelcastInstance = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);
```

```
public class CustomUUIDSerializer implements CompactSerializer<UUID> {
@Override
public @NotNull UUID read(CompactReader reader) {
    return UUID.fromString(Objects.requireNonNull(reader.readString("uuidField")));
}

@Override
public void write(@Nonnull CompactWriter writer, @Nonnull UUID object) {
    writer.writeString("uuidField", object.toString());
}

@Override
public @NotNull Class<UUID> getCompactClass() {
    return UUID.class;
}

@Override
public @NotNull String getTypeName() {
    return "UUID";
}
```

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Compact serializer for the class 'class java.util.UUID can not be registered as it overrides the default serializer for that class provided by Hazelcast.

I of course tried without before and here is the error

com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: The 'class java.util.UUID' cannot be serialized with zero configuration Compact serialization because this type is not supported yet. If you want to serialize 'class net.star.api.impl.common.booster.Booster' which uses this class in its fields, consider writing a CompactSerializer for either the 'class net.star.api.impl.common.booster.Booster' or the 'class java.util.UUID'.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me for HZ 5.4.0-SNAPSHOT version. I have value object with **UUID** field.
I have created **a new serializer** for my value object and added it to **ClientConfig**

**Note** : I have also tried registering a custom serializer for UUID just like you did and that also works for me for HZ 5.4.0-SNAPSHOT version.
I am not posting the code here as I think having a customer serializer for value object is better. Maybe the problem is the HZ version your are using ?

```java
@Getter
@Setter
class UUIDValueObject {

  private UUID uuid;

  public static UUIDValueObject createNew () {
    UUIDValueObject valueObject = new UUIDValueObject();
    valueObject.setUuid(UUID.randomUUID());
    return valueObject;
  }
}
```

The serializer for value object

```java
class UUIDValueObjectSerializer implements CompactSerializer<UUIDValueObject> {
  @Override
  public UUIDValueObject read(CompactReader reader) {
    UUIDValueObject valueObject = new UUIDValueObject();

    String uuidField = reader.readString("uuidField");
    assert uuidField != null;
    UUID uuid = UUID.fromString(uuidField);
    valueObject.setUuid(uuid);
    return valueObject;
  }

  @Override
  public void write(CompactWriter writer, UUIDValueObject uuidValueObject) {
    UUID uuid = uuidValueObject.getUuid();
    writer.writeString("uuidField", uuid.toString());
  }

  @Override
  public String getTypeName() {
    return "UUIDValueObject";
  }

  @Override
  public Class<UUIDValueObject> getCompactClass() {
    return UUIDValueObject.class;
  }
}
```

Then creating a HZ client with the serializer

```java
HazelcastInstance getHazelcastClientInstance() {
  ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();

  clientConfig.getSerializationConfig()
    .getCompactSerializationConfig()
    .addSerializer(new UUIDValueObjectSerializer());

    return HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);
}
```

And I am populating IMap

```java
void populateMap(HazelcastInstance hazelcastClientInstance) {
  IMap<Integer, UUIDValueObject> myMap = 
  hazelcastClientInstance.getMap(MAP_NAME);
  myMap.put(KEY, UUIDValueObject.createNew());
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hello, thank you for answering me and reassuring me that the code should work. I use version 5.3.6 being the latest realese I cannot find the repository for 5.4.0

Comment: You can try with docker image here https://hub.docker.com/layers/hazelcast/hazelcast/5.4.0-SNAPSHOT/images/sha256-cd6feac648fedd9f0b9a60dd90bde94e91e1926cd6d401ac0e22b3f830816d4b?context=explore

Comment: I have the same error even though I launched the 5.4.0 SNAPSHOT image on my kubernetes.... I don't understand why.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Compact serializer for the class 'class java.util.UUID can not be registered as it overrides the default serializer for that class provided by Hazelcast.

Comment: I updated and added world code to uuid serializer, maybe that's the problem?

Comment: Can you share the server start log where it writes the commit id, so that we can check if you are on the right commit version?

Comment: Her logs startup hazelcast -> https://pastebin.com/W8DcRUee

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share an alternative response.

HZ publishes snapshot dependencies to the **oss.sonatype** repository. You can explore an illustrative example project through the following link:
https://github.com/OrcunColak/hzsnapshottutorial

In this project, you'll find:

1. A demonstration of how to utilize Hazelcast snapshot dependencies. **Note that the artifact names differ from the actual artifact names on Maven Central.**
2. An example that successfully implements the CompactSerializer, building upon the details provided in my initial response..

Feel free to clone the demo project and verify its functionality. Importantly, there is no need for Docker, Kubernetes, etc. to run this example.